# Scheme, Check if anything in two lists are the same

Tags: list, scheme, procedure

Is it possible to check two list against each other if anything is the same in them?

(check-list '(hey cookie monkey) '(apple pizza cookie)  ==> #t

I tried something like

```
(define (check-list list element)
  (let ((x list))
  (cond ((null? x) #f)
        ((eq? (car x) (car element)) #t)
        (else (check-list (cdr x) element))))
  (check-list list (cdr element)))
```

I know this is not correctly written but don't know how to tackle this problem.

Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a little confusion. The "big" problem here is how to determine if two lists share at least one element in common, let's write a procedure for that called `element-in-common?`. Before tackling this problem, we need to determine if a *single* element belongs in one list, that's what `check-list` should do (notice that in your code `check-list` receives as a second parameter an *element*, but you're treating it as if it were a *list* of elements).

You don't have to write the `check-list` procedure, it already exists and it's called [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._member%29%29). With that knowledge in hand, we can solve the big problem - how to determine if at least one of the elements in one list (let's call it `lst1`) is in another list (called `lst2`)?

Simple: we iterate over each of the elements in `lst1` using recursion, asking for each one if it belongs in `lst2`. If just one element of `lst1` is a member of `lst2`, we return `#t`. If none of the elements in `lst1` is in `lst2`, we return `#f`. Something like this:

```
(define (element-in-common? lst1 lst2)
  (cond (<???>               ; is the first list empty?
         <???>)              ; then there are no elements in common
        ((member <???> lst2) ; is the current element of `lst1` in `lst2`?
         <???>)              ; then there IS an element in common
        (else                ; otherwise
         (element-in-common? <???> lst2)))) ; advance recursion
```

Don't forget to test your code:

```
(element-in-common? '(hey cookie monkey) '(apple pizza cookie))
=> #t

(element-in-common? '(hey cookie monkey) '(apple pizza pie))
=> #f
```

Comment: Do you know how to check if a pair exist some where in a list?

check-pair? '(apple pie) '(cookie monkey apple pie pizza) ==> #t |||        

check pair? '(apple pie) '(apple cookie monkey pie pizza) ==> #f

Comment: @user2409697 there isn't a built-in procedure for that, you'll have to write one. It's not hard, just check the current element and the next, being careful with the base cases (empty list, list with a single element)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to formulate the process of the solution to a problem in your natural language. Let's simplify the problem a bit.

How do you check if *one* element is contained in a list? One way to do that would be to compare that one element with each element in the list until you found it  - somewhere along the lines you have already done - but not quite. A quick draft would be:

```
(define (member? e lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)       ; empty list doesn't contain e
        (or (eq? e <??>)       ; either the first element is e or
            (member? e <??>))) ; the rest of the list contains e
```

We can use that previous knowledge to solve the real problem at hand. We know how to search for *one* element in a list, and now we need to search for each element in a list in another list.

```
(define (check-list lst1 lst2)
  (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2)) #f  ; empty list(s) share no elements
      (or (member? <??> <??>)            ; first element of lst1 in lst2?
          (member? <??> <??>))))         ; rest of lst1 in lst2?
```

The `<??>` should be substituded with the appropriate expressions for selecting the parts of the lists.

Comment: +1 very well explained and valuable from the didactic point of view

Answer (score 1):

Similar to a prior answer but exploiting logic primitives:

```
(define (intersect? list1 list2)
  (and (not (null? list1))
       (or (member     (car list1) list2)
           (intersect? (cdr list1) list2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are wicket long you might want to hash the first list and then just iterate through the second. This uses R5RS with srfi-69 and for small lists you'll get a little overhead but

```
(require srfi/69); alist->hash-table, hash-table-ref/default 
(define (intersect? list1 list2)
  (let ((hash (alist->hash-table (map (lambda (x) (cons x x)) list2) equal? )))
    (let loop ((list list1))
      (and (not (null? list))
           (or (hash-table-ref/default hash (car list) #f)
               (loop (cdr list)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memq` to check if first element on the first list is on the second list, and if not then check recursively if something in the rest of the first list is in the second list:

```
(define (check-list list1 list2)
  (cond ((null? list1) #f)
        ((memq (car list1) list2) #t)
        (else (check-list (cdr list1) list2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using higher-order functions

in mit-schme

```
(define (check-list L1 L2)
 (apply boolean/or (map (lambda (x) (member? x L2)) L1)))
```

Comment: The order of growth for all solutions so far is exponential. For very large lists, sort both lists first (merge or quick work well on lists) and then compare items in order. It's a more complex procedure, but much faster on the large scale.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define remove-item
  (lambda (lst ele)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (if (equal? (car lst) ele)
            (remove-item (cdr lst) ele)
            (cons (car lst)
                  (remove-item (cdr lst) ele))))))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.